# How to assign hotkeys to comment and uncomment buttons in Excel VB Editor?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a way to assign a hotkey to the comment and uncomment buttons in Excel 2010 VBE. I don't want to resort to something overly complicated like AutoHotkey script or Excel Macro if there's a simple way to do it.

I don't have the reputation to comment on people's answers yet, but in GauravSingh's answer in "How to comment and uncomment blocks of code in the Office VBA Editor," he states adding an Ampersand to the beginning of the button name should allow you to assign it to Alt+C, but this didn't work for me.

Any answer or workaround... or public macro you'd like to share, would be appreciated! :D

Best,

George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need a macro for this. Follow these steps. I will show it for `Comment Block`. I am sure you can replicate it for `UnComment Block`

1. Right-click on the menubar and choose customize.
2. Click on the "New Button" and give the new menu a name

   [image]
3. Next go to the `Commands` Tab and drag the `Comment Block` button to your menubar
4. Right Click on the icon on your menu bar and add the `&` and click on the `Image and Text` option and you are done

   [image]
5. Now you have a keyboard shortcut. ALT-C will comment your selected code.

   [image]

Please ensure that you do not duplicate shortcuts else they will stop working

**In Action**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I learnt a new thing today so thought of sharing.

This works fine with standard toolbar as well. Need following to keep in mind though.

1. Customize popup should be visible on screen. Then right click on any button on standard toolbar also works.
2. & and having Text ON (e.g. Image and Text) are the key points.
3. Need to have this Edit toolbar ON to make shortcuts work.